# Validate an url with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, url-validation

I’m trying to determine whether or not a given string is a valid url or not. And in my scenario, the url can have parameters:

- www.example.com -> OK
- example.test -> OK (although there’s no .test TLD)
- example.com/page.htm?abc=123 -> OK
- xxx/xxx.jpg -> Not OK
- xxx -> Not OK

I’ve tried the [Uri.TryCreate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx), `Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, null);`, but it accepts pretty much anything that has an http:// prefix, i.e. “http://xxx/” is OK.

I can’t use an HTTP request to check/ping the site for performance reasons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why isn't `http://xxx` OK?  See, for example, http://to. (Your browser may choke on that; you may need to add a trailing period)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `http://xxx/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to call `Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out result)`, then check that `result.HostName` contains a `.`

Comment: Thanks, I think your tip did the tricks. I'll play around some more with the Uri object and see if I can something useful out of the properties. :)